# Can we use single sign on for diffrent Form Authentication Sites?

Tags: forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I have 2 different websites

-> webgrants.com

->calgrants.com can be accessed directly or from webgrants

there is link provided for calgrants.com in Webgrants.com
so how can i validate the credentials of user when they click on the link provided. how can i do this .urgent please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better ways to do it, but off the top of my head you can do this:
Assuming they have access to the same(or a common) database you create a table of userId and ticket.
Whenever a user wants a redirection to other website, you create a random value(ticket) and assign that value to the user and store this pair into the database.
You add this ticket to address of the other website, as a parameter. Other website checks the table for that 'ticket' and authenticates the user.

Comment: thanks.actually we should not have to change anything on db side..can i get another suggestion

Comment: you must have some kind of communication channel, which cannot be the parameter on redirection link I assume. Depending on it create a ticket-userId pair, send it to the other party.

Comment: i am beginner i ddn't understand ? u mean..while searching google i found about single sign on,forms authenntication ticket do u have any idea how to implement these for my case